# Use dynamic text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, shell, dom-events

I use asp.net and this code for open local file with IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("d:/11.doc", 1, false);
    }
</script>


<input type="button" value="Run File" onclick="RunFile();"/>
```

result is ok :-)

but I want send address local file to script then run this file:

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run(**AddressFile**, 1, false);
    }
</script>



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
**AddressFile** = "d:/11.doc";
}
```

Comment: you can't mix and match server side code like that.

Comment: Even ViewState["Id"]? please help me...

Comment: Not getting your question.. do you mean you want to send "d:/11.doc" to the script after some button click event ?

Comment: @Sayed: i want send "d:/11.doc" the script after load Page_Load.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the javascript function dynamically from server-side, simply add a parameter to the JS function to take the file name as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile(fileName) {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run(fileName, 1, false);
    }
</script>
```

And then on server-side call the javascript function as so:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType()
,"somekey"
,"RunFile('"+file_parameter_on_server_side+"')",true)";
```

More details and full [example here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)